# How to do CSS for a Line Chart

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am having two line chart's, for one of the line chart I want to remove series line so i tried in this way,

```
#rffLineChart.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: transparent; }

#rffLineChart.default-color0.chart-line-symbol { 
-fx-background-color: white, red; 
}
```

above CSS is not working. show me the way for correct CSS

Below is .fxml file 
**UPDATED**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?import java.lang.*?>
 <?import java.util.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

 <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="917.0" prefWidth="895.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="linechartapp.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
     <LineChart fx:id="lineChart" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="41.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0">
  <xAxis>
    <NumberAxis fx:id="xAxis" autoRanging="false" side="BOTTOM" upperBound="1600.0" />
  </xAxis>
  <yAxis>
    <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" autoRanging="false" lowerBound="-130.0" side="LEFT" upperBound="30.0" />
  </yAxis>
</LineChart>
<Button fx:id="btnLoad" layoutX="396.0" layoutY="866.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Load Data" />
<Button fx:id="btnClear" layoutX="501.0" layoutY="867.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefWidth="55.0" text="Clear" />
<LineChart fx:id="rffLineChart" layoutY="436.0" prefWidth="840.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="41.0">
  <xAxis>
    <NumberAxis fx:id="rffXAxis" autoRanging="false" side="BOTTOM" upperBound="1600.0" />
  </xAxis>
  <yAxis>
    <NumberAxis fx:id="rffYAxis" autoRanging="false" lowerBound="-130.0" side="LEFT" upperBound="30.0" />
  </yAxis>
</LineChart>
   </children>
 </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: remove java tag... and all the others except css!

Comment: why Java and Javafx??

Comment: Can you show us the HTML you want to style?

Comment: if i remove Java tag ,series line is applying for both line chart's. But i want for a specific line chart

Comment: In one of line chart just i want to show dots, rather than connecting with lines. so i opted for the above CSS

Comment: @LuigiCortese I disagree because not everyone familiar with CSS will be familiar with JavaFX CSS specifics and exceptions.

Comment: @Jost The css in this case is styling a Java application through the JavaFX framework not HTML, the removal of `java` and `javafx` tags feels unwarranted.

Comment: @CeilingGecko Ok, sorry - added them back

Comment: JavaFX CSS and CSS is not exactly the same. There are CSS style classes you need to know to style some JavaFX elements. And not everything which is possible with CSS is also possible in JavaFx.

Comment: @pavankumar can you show how you create your line-chart, is there a fxml?

Comment: @NDY i updated .fxml file.

Comment: please go through following link
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764324/how-to-write-css-code-for-particular-control