# How to write CSS code for particular control

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I developed a JavaFx stand alone application, which is having following controls

Two sets of -- Button btn1,btn2;
Two sets of -- LineChart lc1,lc2;

In .css file i wrote following code :

```
#btn1{
-fx-background-color:red;
}

#btn2{
-fx-background-color:green;
}

#lc1.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: green; }
#lc1.default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: #e9967a, red;
-fx-background-radius:0;
-fx-padding: 1px;
}

#lc2.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: transparent; }
#lc2.default-color0.chart-line-symbol { -fx-background-color: #e9967a, red;
-fx-background-radius:0;
-fx-padding: 1px;
}
```

for btn1 and btn2 background colors which are taken from .css file are applying.

But for Line Charts i.e lc1, lc2 , the css code is not working.

please help me to show sample .css for linecharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need an extra space between the id of the chart and the chart line class:

```
#lc1 .default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: green; }
    ^-- here
```